# Overriding return type of derived template class

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, polymorphism

If I have some abstract class **A** with a virtual function **Clone** and a template class **B** that inherits **A** and overrides **Clone**, I want to make this function return type **B<T>** whereas the original (in **A**) returns type **A**.

I tried this but the compiler is telling me I cannot return an abstract class:

```
class A
{
public:
    virtual A Clone() const = 0;
};

template <typename T>
class B : public A
{
private:
    T value;
public:
    B<T> Clone() const override
    {
        return B<T>(value);
    }
};
```

I believe this is not possible unless I return **A*** and **B<T>*** from A's Clone and B's Clone, but I don't want to create this on the heap. Is there a way to do this? (I don't want to take a pointer to where to write the clone to either if at all possible.)

**Note:** I left out some of the "noise" like the constructors and such.

Comment: *but I don't want to create this on the heap* -- Pointers need not have anything to do with the heap.

Comment: I understand that, but I want to return a B<T>.

Comment: Could I return a B<void> from A's Clone and override B<void> to just not have a field?

Comment: This seems to be turning into an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  On a high-level, what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I'm trying to have a sort of "property" type for a decoder for a custom file format that consists of the property's type followed by its value. My class holds a vector of Property* which I can read a property doing: sect.ReadProperty<int>("PropName") and write to one doing sect.WriteProperty<float>("PropName", 3.14f).

Comment: Have you considered using `std::vector` of [boost::any](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/any.html) or [std::any](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any)?

Comment: Oh didn't know that was a thing, will look into it thank you.

Answer (score 0):

No, values cannot do this.  Values have specific and fixed storage and type.

You can create polymorphic value types, like `std::function`, but it only uses inheritance as an implementation detail (at best).

`std::any` is a polymorphic value type with nearly no interface; it uses SBO or the heap depending on contents size.   Augmenting it with additional interfaces isn't extremely difficult.